# R2 Gazebo simulator

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am traying install R2 simulator on my pc. I follow steps mentioned in this [link](https://gitlab.com/nasa-jsc-robotics/robonaut2/wikis/R2%20Gazebo%20Simulation) .

When I run this command in terminal.
rosdep install -y -i --from-paths src

I got this error message;

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
robot_instance: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [shared_memory_transport]

Thanks for advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255439/r2-gazebo-simulator/) by [repekcan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29003/repekcan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

Try running the lines of code below that chunk:

```
cd ~/r2_sim/src/robot_instance
git checkout 2016_11_7_ar_demo
```

Then try to rerun from the line:

```
rosdep install -y -i --paths src
```

And continue onwards to Robonaut glory!

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [Mary.Hewitt](https://answers.ros.org/users/29804/mary.hewitt/) with karma: 16 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0